# What is the format of sosex heap index file?

Tags: .net, windbg, sosex

What is the format of sosex heap index file? I would like to parse it and analyze the content.

I checked stevetechspot blog and cannot find the info there. Seems Steve hasn't updated the blog for several years.

Comment: Contact info is listed under sosex!help. Feel free to email any time.

Comment: Have you reecived an answer? If so, you could self-answer your own question and let the community benefit from your knowledge.